# Dev Express chart Not Updating Second Time in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

For the first time when I run my window application it will successfully run, but when I change the database column and binding then it gives me an error that specific data column is not there in database; also I am make null chart datasource but it gives an error. Please help.

```
Dim ctrArr As Integer
Dim serCnt As Integer
Dim series1 As New Series
Dim seriesFound As Boolean = False

For serCnt = 0 To ctrChart.Series.Count - 1
    ctrChart.Series(0).ArgumentDataMember = ""
    ctrChart.Series(0).ValueDataMembers(0) = ""
    ctrChart.Series(0).Visible = False

Next


For ctrArr = 0 To gStrYAxisParamArray.Length - 1   'deptname'     
    For serCnt = 0 To ctrChart.Series.Count - 1
        If UCase(Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr))) = UCase(ctrChart.Series(serCnt).Name.ToString) Then
            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ArgumentDataMember = ""
            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ValueDataMembers(0) = ""
            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).Visible = True

            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ArgumentDataMember = gxAxis
            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ValueDataMembers.Item(0) = Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr))
            seriesFound = True

            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If seriesFound = False Then
        series1 = New Series(Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr)).ToString, ViewType.Bar)
        'ctrChart.Series.AddRange(New Series() {series1, series2})
        ctrChart.Series.Add(series1)
        series1.ArgumentDataMember = ""
        series1.ValueDataMembers(0) = ""
        series1.Visible = True
        series1.ArgumentDataMember = gxAxis
        series1.Label.Border.Visible = False
        series1.ValueDataMembers(0) = Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr))
        series1.LegendText = Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr).ToString)
    End If
    seriesFound = False
Next

cmbSeries.Items.Clear()
For ctrArr = 0 To ChrtStockDept.Series.Count - 1
    With cmbSeries.Items
        cmbSeries.Items.Add(ChrtStockDept.Series(ctrArr).Name.ToString)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: 1) The loop `For serCnt = 0 To ctrChart.Series.Count - 1` isn't using `serCnt` in the loop. Could that be something to do with it? 2) Which line does the error appear on?

Comment: Sir I have use That Sercnt variable on loop but its not effect on code  because it  just clear the Series from chart  . And sir Error is inside the     FOR LOOP   ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ArgumentDataMember = gxAxis
            ctrChart.Series(serCnt).ValueDataMembers.Item(0) = Trim(gStrYAxisParamArray(ctrArr))  WHEN I TRYING TO CHANGE ARGUMENTDATAMEMBER  OR VALUE DATAMEMBER

Comment: Where do the values in `gStrYAxisParamArray` come from? Could it be that there really is, say, a space character at the end of the column name and that space character is being removed by the `Trim`?

Comment: gStrYAxisParamArray is  y exis value for display series for example if we want to show piece and waight for the perticular department that piece and waight will be the value of  gStrYAxisParamArray  which is assign to value datamember of chart. first  time it will run correctly but second time it will give an error that column is not available on datasource . and trim use for remove space if available .